# HttpContext and TelemetryInitializer

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I want to attach the user's "client_id" claim as a property to every request sent to Application Insights.

From what I've read, I should be implementing `ITelemetryInitializer` but I need the `HttpContext` for the request in order to retrieve "client_id". See my initialiser:

```
public class ClaimTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        this.AddTelemetryContextPropertFromClaims(telemetry, "client_id");
    }

    private void AddTelemetryContextPropertFromClaims(ITelemetry telemetry, string claimName)
    {
        if (HttpContext != null)
        {
            var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;

            var claim = HttpContext.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals(claimName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

            if (claim != null)
            {
                telemetry.Context.Properties[claimName] = claim.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I could create an action filter to set the context each time, but this feels awful:

```
public class TrackClaimsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var initialiser = TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.OfType<ClaimTelemetryInitializer>().Single();

        initialiser.HttpContext = context.HttpContext;

        return base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should implement the [WebTelemetryInitializerBase](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/master/Src/Web/Web.Shared.Net/Implementation/WebTelemetryInitializerBase.cs) which provides you the HttpContext.

Your code should look like:

```
public class ClaimTelemetryInitializer : WebTelemetryInitializerBase
{
    protected override void OnInitializeTelemetry(
            HttpContext platformContext,
            RequestTelemetry rootRequestTelemetry, 
            ITelemetry telemetry) {

            var claim = HttpContext.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals(claimName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

            if (claim != null)
            {
                telemetry.Context.Properties[claimName] = claim.Value;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem compatible with ASP.NET Core / MVC6.

Comment: I've asked [another question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418682/webtelemetryinitializerbase-in-asp-net-core-mvc6).

Comment: How can you derive from `WebTelemetryInitializerBase` if its ctor is internal (bases on 2.2.0 sources)?

Comment: Likewise with TelemetryInitializerBase

Comment: WebTelemetryInitializerBase uses internally HttpContext.Current

Comment: Has anyone found a resolution for this issue?  I'm not able to access HttpContext with an MVC6 application.

Comment: This is NOT a solution as you can not inherit from a class with internal ctor!!!

Comment: FWIW the modern equivalent to this class is `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.TelemetryInitializers.TelemetryInitializerBase`

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest to inject an HttpContextAccessor instance in the ClaimTelemetryInitializer class's constructor, and then you could use it to extract values from the HttpContext. 
Or, even better, create a base class for your TelemetryInitializer, and use it's constructor to inject the HttpContextAccessor instance.

For example:

```
    protected ClaimTelemetryInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var context = this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        if (context == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var claim = context.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals(claimName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        //Do logic here...
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as the constructor is only hit once for the lifetime of the app even if the service registration uses Transient or Scoped.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't realize IHttpContextAccessor creates an object reference so the constructor doesn't need to be hit multiple times.  This does work.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for .NET Core and later.

Answer (score 2):

I wish this were designed into AppInsights but you can directly use the static `HttpContext.Current`. You can use it's per-request `Items` dictionary as a short term (near stateless) storage space to deliver your custom values to the custom telemetry handler.

So try

```
class AppInsightCustomProps : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
        // Is this a TrackRequest() ?
        if (requestTelemetry == null) return;

        var httpCtx = HttpContext.Current;
        if (httpCtx != null)
        {
            var customPropVal = (string)httpCtx.Items["PerRequestMyCustomProp"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customPropVal))
            {
                requestTelemetry.Properties["MyCustomProp"] = customPropVal;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to program the desired custom property, anywhere in your request pipeline have something like

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Items["PerRequestMyCustomProp"] = myCustomPropValue;
}
```