# WebTelemetryInitializerBase in ASP.NET Core / MVC6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, azure-application-insights

Is there an MVC6 compatible version of `WebTelemetryInitializerBase` that would work with ASP.NET Core (on the full .NET Framework)?

See [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413032/httpcontext-and-telemetryinitializer/38413803#38413803) where I asked how to get `HttpContext` in my temeletry initializers. Unfortunately I didn't specify that I was using MVC 6 and thus no `System.Web.HttpContext`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a version of this for aspnetcore. Check out the [Microsoft Application Insights for ASP.NET Core applications](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/) repo.

There is an implementation of getting the WebUser found in [/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/TelemetryInitializers/WebUserTelemetryInitializer.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/TelemetryInitializers/WebUserTelemetryInitializer.cs) which you can use as a guide.

The [`TelemetryInitializerBase`](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/TelemetryInitializers/TelemetryInitializerBase.cs) class is the one that consumes the [`IHttpContextAccessor`](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/1.0.0-rc1/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNet/Http/IHttpContextAccessor/index.html) which is used to get the HttpContext.

From there you can get the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext.User`](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Http/HttpContext/#prop-Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext.User) which is they type of `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal`