# How do I get the correct headers passed to WebAPI telemetry?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

First I tried the code from this Q&A: [HttpContext and TelemetryInitializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413032/httpcontext-and-telemetryinitializer/), the part where it says "I could create an action filter to set the context each time, but this feels awful."

Using the linked code, I tested using debugger breakpoints to see if there was a problem with the Active field being global. I did this with just two incoming web requests.

It seemed TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.OfType().Single() was different for each request instead of global. Which is what I wanted. But in production I saw a race condition in that the wrong headers were being attached to the wrong requests. This was done by inspecting the Azure Log Analytics in the dependencies table, specifically the operation_Name versus an HTTP header from the UI that I attached to customDimensions.

Given that the linked Stackoverflow Q&A had a low rating I decided to try alternate code and found some from the official documentation here: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Configure#add-request-level-properties-for-all-telemetry-items.

I am still getting incorrect headers applied in customDimensions. Could this be due to telemetry sampling or some other reason that I'm not aware of?

A generic form of my ITelemetryInitializer:

```
public class TrackingTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public TrackingTelemetryInitializer(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this._httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var headers = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers;
        if (headers.ContainsKey("Foobar"))
        {
            telemetry.Context.Properties["Foobar"] = headers["Foobar"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say without running your code, but at initial glance it may be an issue of passing by reference instead of passing by value. You might want to perform a copy of the headers, rather than referencing to it.

Comment: The type of headers["Foobar"] is string and so is telemetry.Context.Properties["Foobar"]. String is immutable so pass by reference shouldn't be the problem. Or did you mean the collection of headers?