# Application Insights TelemetryInitializer and HttpContext.User

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, azure-application-insights

In WebApi2 project, I have custom Claim and I want to send this as custom property for every request.

I implemented TelemetryInitializer but User in HttpContext is always null.

```
public class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{   
    var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
    if (requestTelemetry == null) return;

    var user= HttpContext.Current.User;

    // values from header are wokring
     requestTelemetry.Context.Properties["abc"] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Get("abc");

}
```

What would be correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpContext and TelemetryInitializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38413032/httpcontext-and-telemetryinitializer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your description, I checked the [Visual Studio Application Insights SDK for .NET Web Applications](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/tree/master) and found [WebTelemetryInitializerBase.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/master/Src/Web/Web.Shared.Net/Implementation/WebTelemetryInitializerBase.cs) has a abstract method `OnInitializeTelemetry` as follows:

```html
protected abstract void OnInitializeTelemetry(
            HttpContext platformContext,
            RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry, 
            ITelemetry telemetry);
```

You could inherit the `WebTelemetryInitializerBase` and override the `OnInitializeTelemetry` method which provides the `HttpContext` parameter and you could retrieve your claims.

**UPDATE:**

You could also inherit other TelemetryInitializers which inherit `WebTelemetryInitializerBase`.

For example, the [UserTelemetryInitializer](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/75373e57dcf8d646c54ee188461c373f2cc98939/Src/Web/Web.Shared.Net/UserTelemetryInitializer.cs), and you could define your custom TelemetryInitializer as follows:

```
public class CustomTelemetryInitializer : UserTelemetryInitializer  //WebTelemetryInitializerBase
{
    protected override void OnInitializeTelemetry(
            HttpContext platformContext,
            RequestTelemetry rootRequestTelemetry,
            ITelemetry telemetry)
    {

        var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)platformContext.User.Identity).Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("<custom-claim-name>", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)); ;

        if (claim != null)
        {
            telemetry.Context.Properties["<<custom-claim-name>>"] = claim.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover, you could also search other TelemetryInitializers via [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=WebTelemetryInitializerBase+&type=).

Comment: I can't inherit WebTelemetryInitializerBase because of internal constructor.

Comment: Sorry for not paying attention about this limitation. I just updated my answer with the sample code, you could refer to the updated part.